# Password input is the only field that won't highlight on selection

Tags: html, css, authentication

For some reason the password field won't highlight when I click on it, meanwhile the other fields are highlighted upon selection.

> My code is exactyly the same for all fields, but the password field
>   reacts differently. I know the answer must be something simple, so
>   please let me know what I'm missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbm1ommt/

```
<div id="Personal"  class="formDiv">

            <!-- Register Form -->

            <div class="user_signup" id="user_register1">

        <form class="signup-form">


          <input class="fullname" type="text" name="fullname"  placeholder="First and Last Name" />

          <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address"/>

          <input class="pass" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="New password" />



            <div class="btnwrapper2">

            <input class="signupbtn" value="Sign up!" type="submit"/> 

          </div>

         </div>

        </form>

            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.user_signup {display: block;}
.user_signup label {display: block; margin-bottom:5px; color:#666;}
.user_signup input[type="text"], .user_signup input[type="password"], .user_signup input[type="email"] {display: block; width:100%; padding:15px; border-radius:5px; border:1.2px solid #DDD; font-size:20px; color:#333; font-family:arial; margin-bottom:20px; box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}}

.user_signup input[type="password"]:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color:#39F;
   }

.user_signup input[type="text"]:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
   }

.user_signup input[type="email"]:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F;
   }


   .signupcheckbox {margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:40px; margin-left:4px;}




.signupbtn { background:gray; display:block; width:100%; padding:20px; margin:0px 0; font-size:20px; margin-top:15px; border-radius:5px; box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; color:#FFF; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;background:gray; cursor:pointer; outline:none !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none; border:none;} 


.signupbtn:hover {background:blue; color:white;}



.btnwrapper2 {display:inline-block; width:100%; height:auto; position:relative; clear:both; margin-top:0px; margin-right:10px;
}


.signuptitle {font-size:40px; margin-bottom:15px; }

.loginline{text-align:left; float:left; display:inline-block; margin-left:7px; margin-top:15px; color:#A1A1A1; border-top:1px solid #DDD; width:100%;}

.loginline a {text-decoration:none; color:#39F; }

.loginline a:hover {text-decoration:underline; color:#39F; }


.signup-form {text-align:left; float:left; display:inline-block;  }

.signup-form  p {float:left; margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px; clear:both;}


.dropdownform {text-align:left; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:20px; clear:both;}

.dropdownform select {text-decoration:none; color:#333; font-size:20px; }

.dropdowntext{font-size:20px;  }


.form-group { border: 1px solid red;}




.logintext {float:left; cursor: pointer; color:#39F; font-size:20px; text-decoration:none;  margin-top:10px; margin-left:4px;}

.logintext:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not really an answer, but when I added:
    .user_signup input[type="password"]:active {
        border-color: #39F;
    }
it works. (On click the border comes up until click-release)
CSS is the temple of simple wonders. I will keep looking at it for a while, because I had encountered something similar at about a year ago. Will come back - hopefully soon.*

---

### EDIT (2.0) with the solution

I have no idea why firefox cannot handle the way you did it, but here is a working solution for all browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/eeu9nhxh/2/

**The key part is:**

```
.user_signup input:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #39F!important;
   }
```

It is giving all your inputs this focus-styling.

Hope it helped,

Andrew

Comment: Additional info: this problem only occurs in Firefox as far as I see. Right?

Comment: Thank you for answering. The issue occurs on all browsers, but on firefox there's no visible highlight, and on chrome the highlight is thicker

Comment: actually no. Now the highlights don't work for chrome, and on firefox the highilight on the password box is different.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eeu9nhxh/2/ <--- this is working like a charm in Firefox (up-to-date version) and Chrome (up-to-date version).

Comment: Please edit the solution again and add the answer which is to remove the extra { and add the correct code then I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen your comment for a while, sorry. I edited the solution again, included the jsfiddle. I'm glad it worked out!